# PHP Success message showing inside of an error box

Tags: php, html, email

I am using this PHP email script:

```php
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $recipient = "contact@domain.com";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailheader, $message) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='contact.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000;'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

When I test the form, it sends me an email as intended, but displays this message:

[image]

Here is the HTML for the form:

```html
<form id="lift" action="mail.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="my-3">
        <div class="loading">Loading</div>
        <div class="error-message"></div>
        <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
</form>
```

I searched my files and could not find anything containing "Error:", I'm not sure if maybe it's coming from bootstrap possibly? I do have bootstrap linked to the HTML.

Comment: That "Error" isn't coming from this code. `die()` ends the script, so it can't echo the next line after that. Also, you have `!` at the end of `Error` but that's not in the screenshot.

Comment: Search your code for `Error:`

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure what it could be coming from unless it's in bootstrap? I have that linked to the document, but not where is there an "Error:" specifically.

Also, where should I put the echo to make that work properly?

Comment: I can't help you find it, all I can do is promise that it's not from that `die("Error!")`

Comment: @Barmar Okay thank you very much!

Comment: It looks like you're using Bootstrap Form Validation. Go here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/validation/ and read the Server section

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple `if` statement? It seem you are using bootstrap form validation so I've commented out your client side html that really does nothing and now you have only the server reply.

Go here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/validation/ to see which css classes in the form you can toggle on or off using PHP.

#### PHP code at the top of the page:

```
<?php

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // collect value of input field
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $subject = $_POST['subject'];
      $message = $_POST['message'];

      if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['subject']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
        echo "Must complete all fields in form.";
      } else if(mail($recipient, $subject, $mailheader, $message)) {
      echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='contact.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000;'> Return Home</a>";
      } else {
        die("Error!");
      }
    }

 ?>
```

.

#### HTML code below PHP code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Email Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Email Form</h1>

        <form id="lift" action="mail.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form mt-4">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
        </div>
        </div>

       <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        </div>

      <!-- Commented out because why? -->
        <!-- <div class="my-3"> -->
        <!-- <div class="loading">Loading</div> -->
        <!-- <div class="error-message"></div> -->
        <!-- <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div> -->
        <!-- </div> -->

        <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
        </form>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This didn't get rid of the error, it still looks the same. Somehow there is something telling it to throw up an error message at every response. I can't seem to find the code causing that.

Comment: So the PHP mail() function doesn't work out of the box. What is the error message?

Comment: The script functions perfectly in the sense that I receive an email and there is no error shown on the server itself, but just like in the screenshot on the original post, it shows an "Error: Thank you!" message, so for some reason it's showing the Success message in an error box.